# Touch out from app window AIR for Android

Tags: android, flash, actionscript

I create app for android in Adobe Flash Professional.
It is fragment of code.

```html
stage.addEventListener( TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, _out );
 
function _out( e:TouchEvent):void
{
  trace( "OUT!" );
}
```

When I move on some view object I obtain message. When I move on the screen and then move out the area of the screen I'm not receiving messages. What do?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you are trying to trigger a function whenever the cursor is rolled out of the stage. In such a case, a naive option is check the coordinate of the mouse an to check if its on the stage or not. Whenever the cursor crosses the stage dimensions, the function can be triggered.

Another way is to use a transparent object on the stage and check collision of the mouse with that. Whenever the collision detection returns false, the function will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

1. TOUCH_OUT will not work on Windows debugging sessions, but it will work on your Android. Don't worry.
2. To avoid the event being triggered by on-stage objects, just set the property *mouseChildren* of all your MovieClips to *false*.